# using fontforge module without ffpython.exe

Tags: python, module, fontforge

I discovered that in one of my builds there is the file ffpython.exe which runs python with the module I looked for: fontforge.
My question is how to make it permanent like other modules. I mean that anytime that I'll open my regular python interpret, the module will be installed like other modules, without using ffpython.exe.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Building fontforge (also) as a python extension
>
> If you want to write python scripts in normal python (as opposed to
>   within the python embedded in fontforge)
>
> $ ./configure --enable-pyextension

http://fontforge.org/source-build.html